# How do I apply pmax to an xts object in r?

Tags: r, xts

I have an xts object of realized (stock) volatilities and I want to impose a minimum volatility for each stock/column.  Here's a sample that I can't get to work correctly.  It cycles through the minimum vol vector strangely.  Thank you.

```
require(xts)
set.seed(3)    
A <- matrix(runif(18, max=0.30), ncol=3)
A.xts <- xts(A, Sys.Date()-6:1)
Min_Vols <- c(.10, .20, .30)
B <- pmax(as.matrix(A.xts), Min_Vols)
A.xts; B
```

The above generates

```
                 [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
2015-08-28 0.05041246 0.03739003 0.16021061
2015-08-29 0.24225492 0.08838028 0.16717483
2015-08-30 0.11548271 0.17328298 0.26037585
2015-08-31 0.09832030 0.18929378 0.24891261
2015-09-01 0.18063020 0.15360477 0.03343475
2015-09-02 0.18131822 0.15150717 0.21110651
                [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
2015-08-28 0.1000000 0.1000000 0.1602106
2015-08-29 0.2422549 0.2000000 0.2000000
2015-08-30 0.3000000 0.3000000 0.3000000
2015-08-31 0.1000000 0.1892938 0.2489126
2015-09-01 0.2000000 0.2000000 0.2000000
2015-09-02 0.3000000 0.3000000 0.3000000
```

Where I want B to be:

```
                 [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
2015-08-28 0.10000000 0.20000000 0.30000000
2015-08-29 0.24225492 0.20000000 0.30000000
2015-08-30 0.11548271 0.20000000 0.30000000
2015-08-31 0.10000000 0.20000000 0.30000000
2015-09-01 0.18063020 0.20000000 0.30000000
2015-09-02 0.18131822 0.20000000 0.30000000
```

Comment: Use and show `set.seed` to generate your example data. Show expected output. Guessing that you want `sapply(1:ncol(A),function(i) pmax(A[,i],Min_Vols[i]))`.

Comment: Thank you, A. Webb, I made edits as shown.

Comment: My real code acts different from the example above, and generates the following error when I run it: `sapply(1:ncol(Vols.xts), function(i) pmax(Vols.xts[,i],Min_Vols[i]))` whch gave:
`Error in array(r, dim = d, dimnames = if (!(is.null(n1 <- names(x[[1L]])) &  : 
  length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent`  Ultimately to fix it I had to transform the xts object with `as.matrix(Vols.xts[,i])` and then transform it back.  This was the issue I was having.  I see that @Joshua-Ulrich shows this below.  I don't know why this error doesn't occur on the simple A B version in our sample code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `sapply` to impose your constraints across the columns

```
B<-sapply(1:ncol(A),function(i) pmax(A[,i],Min_Vols[i]))
xts(B,index(A.xts))

#>                 [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> 2015-08-28 0.1000000  0.2  0.3
#> 2015-08-29 0.2422549  0.2  0.3
#> 2015-08-30 0.1154827  0.2  0.3
#> 2015-08-31 0.1000000  0.2  0.3
#> 2015-09-01 0.1806302  0.2  0.3
#> 2015-09-02 0.1813182  0.2  0.3
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple options. You could create a matrix to pass to `pmax`:

```
MinVolMatrix <- matrix(Min_Vols, nrow(A), ncol(A), byrow=TRUE)
B <- as.xts(pmax(as.matrix(A.xts), MinVolMatrix))
```

You could use `apply` (note that you have to transpose the result, due to how `apply` constructs its output):

```
B <- as.xts(t(apply(A.xts, 1, pmax, Min_Vols)))
```

Comment: You can simplify and avoid creating a new matrix by using `B<- matrix(pmax(Min_Vols, t(A)), byrow=TRUE, ncol=3)`